# Warning message: --entry type for "abnt-url-package" isn't style defined --line 199 of file abntext2options.bib

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, warnings, abnt

I'm getting this warning message when running bibtex on my .bib file and I get a weird entry in my bibliography.

[EDIT] Added MWEB:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{abntex2cite}

\begin{document}
\bibliography{mweb}        %use a bibtex bibliography file refs.bib

\cite{key}

\bibliographystyle{plain}  %use the plain bibliography style

\end{document}
```

mweb.bib:

```
@book{key,
author = {Author, A.},
year = {2001},
title = {Title},
publisher = {Publisher},
}
```

output:

[image: reference problem]

warning:

[image: warning]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se.  Instead of posting your preamble (most of which isn't relevant) try reproduce the error with a minimal document that contains *only* the `\documentclass` line, `\usepackage{abntex2cite}`, `\begin{document} ... \end{document}`.  Then find the particular entry in the `.bib` file that gives the warning and add that to the question, not a link to your entire `.bib` file. You should also load `hyperref` last in the package loading order.

Comment: I see from the documentation that you're supposed to load `hyperref` before `abntex2cite`, so I would do that by loading both very late in the order.

Comment: The basic problem is that you are using a `.bib` entry type that the `.bst` file (`abnt2tex-alf` or `abnt2tex-num`) is not set up to handle. See [I get a warning that the entry type of one my cites “isn’t style-file defined”](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/338769) and  [what does "Warning--entry type for "..." isn't style-file defined" mean?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/56951).

Comment: I've replaced all the howpublished with note, try to remove all the url = and \url but I still get the error, it seems that's trying to include abntex2cite into the bibliography, I've noticed this other warning:
all relevant fields are empty in abnt-url-package=url

Comment: Without a minimal document to show what you're doing, it's hard to help.

Comment: what do you need?

Comment: Exactly what I described in my first comment. See [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: @AlanMunn I've added the mweb

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `plain` bibliography style with `abntex2cite`, which defines (and loads) its own bibliography style.  So the following document compiles without warnings or errors:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
author = {Author, A.},
year = {2001},
title = {Title},
publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{abntex2cite}
\begin{document}

\cite{key}
\bibliography{\jobname}        %use a bibtex bibliography file refs.bib

\end{document}
```